# Python PyMT script crashing on open

Tags: python, crash

I am attempting to learn the PyMT library and am trying to implement a simple program that i found on the web. however every time i open the script in PyMT it crashes as soon as it opens is there any thing that is incorrect in my code that would be cause it to be crashing?

```
from pymt import *

class Tracer(MTWidget):

def init(self):
    self.lines = []

def on_touch_down(self, touch):

    touch.userdata['line'] = list(touch.pos)
    self.lines.append (touch.userdata['line'])

def on_touch_move(self, touch):
    touch.userdata['line'].extend(touch.pos)

def draw(self) :
    for touch in getAvailableTouchs():
        drawLine(line)


w = MTWindow()

canvas = MTScatterPlane()
canvas.add_widget(Tracer())

w.add_widget(canvas)
runTouchApp()
```

Comment: What output do you see when it crashes?

Comment: i don't see anything it crashes before it does anything at all

Comment: Is your code correctly indented?

Comment: Just checking: the improper indentation shown above (eg.  init(), on_touch_down() etc. should be indented "under" Tracer)...  is this just an artefact of the code snippet display or is the actual script with such errrors ?

Comment: its an artifact of the code snippet in my script it is all properly indented

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SO apparently if you are importing the .py file which is what PyMT does you can't create the ui....does anyone know how i would go about setting up a UI then?

Answer (score 0):

I've installed pymt in my mac, and I couldn't run the examples using python command.
I've foolwed the instructions on README, and ran the examples using pymt command.